How to implement event delegation
So I have a partial named (action-request-partial) that I created that loads dynamically into another partial(center). The thing is I want to be able to upload files from each of those partials (action-request partial) but my issue is that the javascript I have only responds to the input file field in the first dynamically loaded (action - request partial) I read online about event delegation but I don't understand it enough to implement it. Here's my code if any of you can help figure out a solution ?
<div class="uw-actions-tab-display">
    <div class="uw-section" id="assigned_section">      
      <label for="assigned-to-value">Assigned to: </label>
      <p id="assigned-to-value"><%= action.assigned_to_username %></p>
      <label for="supervisor-value">Supervisor: </label>
      <p id="supervisor-value"><%= action.created_by_username %></p>
      <label for="date_created">Created on: </label>
      <p id="date_created"> <%= action.created_on %></p>
      <label for="date_due">Due On: </label>
      <p id="date_due"><%= action.due_date %></p>
      <p id = "uw-id"><b> Id:</b> <%=action.uw_action_id %></p>
    </div>

    <div class="uw-section" id="request_type_section">
      <label for="Request Type">Request Type: </label>
      <p id="request_additional_docs" class = "request_type_docs"> </a>*Additional Documents <%= action.additional_documents %> </p>
      <p id="request_endorsement_docs" class = "request_type_docs"> *Endorsements <%= action.endorsements %></p>
      <p id="request_home_ownership_docs" class = "request_type_docs"> *Proof of Home Ownership <%= action.proof_of_home_ownership %></p>
      <p id="request_drivers_license_docs" class = "request_type_docs"> *Drivers License <%= action.drivers_license %></p>
      <p id="request_fl_license_check" class = "request_type_docs"> *FL DL CHECK <%= action.fl_dl_check %></p>
      <input type ="file" multiple id = "request_type_upload"></input> 
      <button type = "button" id = "request_type_section_upload_btn">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="uw-section" id="uploaded_section">
      <label>Uploaded: </label>
      <p id="uploaded_additional_docs" class = "uploaded_docs" >*Additional Documents <%= action.additional_documents %> </p>
      <p id="uploaded_endorsement_docs" class = "uploaded_docs" >*Endorsements <%= action.endorsements %></p>
      <p id="uploaded_home_ownership_docs"  class = "uploaded_docs" >*Proof of Home Ownership <%= action.proof_of_home_ownership %></p>
      <p id="uploaded_drivers_license_docs"  class = "uploaded_docs">*Drivers License <%= action.drivers_license %> </p>
      <p id="uploaded_fl_license_check"  class = "uploaded_docs">*FL DL CHECK <%= action.fl_dl_check %></p>
    </div>

    <div class="uw-section" id="status_section">
      <label>Satus: </label>
      <p id="completed_status">*Completed</p>
      <p id="in_progress_status">*In Progress</p>
      <p id="t_docs_status">*T-Docs <br> Received</p>
      <p id="requested_status">*T-Docs <br> Requested</p>
    </div>
  </div>

const requestTypeDocumentSubmitBtn = document.getElementById('request_type_section_upload_btn');
const uwActionID = document.getElementById('uw-id').innerText;
    
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target && event.target.id === 'request_type_section_upload_btn') {
      const requestTypeUploadedDocs = document.getElementById('request_type_upload').files;
      const formData = new FormData();
      const uwActionID = document.getElementById('uw-id').innerText;

      Array.from(requestTypeUploadedDocs).forEach(document => {
          if (document.name.includes("additional documents")) {
              formData.append('additional_documents', document);
              console.log('additional documents received');
          } else if (document.name.includes("proof of ownership")) {
              formData.append('proof_of_ownership', document);
              console.log('proof of ownership received');
          } else if (document.name.includes("endorsements")) {
              formData.append('endorsements', document);
              console.log('endorsements received');
          } else if (document.name.includes("drivers license")) {
              formData.append('drivers_license', document);
              console.log('drivers license received');
          }
          console.log(uwActionID);
      });

      fetch('/upload_documents', { 
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
      })
      .then(response => {
          console.log('Server Responded !');
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
      });
  }
});


You do know that id must be unique at all times, meaning you can never have more than a single element per document with any given id value?

Thats true so should I use class instead and use QuerySelectorAll? But wouldnt that create a whole new array....

Do you think ill be able to use query select all to select all the sumbit btns and for each of the partials and create an event listener and include my logic ?

Event delegation happens on the client, the Express code is irrelevant.

The code I posted is all client side code to handle the posting of files from the front end.. So I dont get what your saying.

Use partial = event.target.closest(".action-request-partial") to get the container of the element they clicked on, and partial.querySelectorAll() to find other elements within that container.

Conforming to the expectation I initially stated with regard to id, getElementById will always only return the first match in a document.
